# Running Apply with Function of prime number on data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I am looking up to index data frame by applying prime Number function on rows of data frame using **apply**. the given output should be holding out rows which have any or all numbers as prime. Example data frame name c4:

`c1 c2 c3
1   8  2  6
2   9  5  4
3  10  4  5
4   7  1  8
5   3  1  2
6   7  5  9
7   5  1  4
8   2  1  3
9   7  2  4
10 10  4  8`

the given output should be

`c1 c2 c3
1  8  2  6
2  9  5  4
3 10  4  5
4  7  1  8
5  3  1  2
6  7  5  9
7  5  1  4
8  2  1  3
9  7  2  4`

removing the tenth row. 
the code I am using for the prime number is

`prime.function<- 
function (x){
 if(x == 2){
   return(TURE)
 } else if (any(x %% 2: (x - 1) == 0)){
   return(FALSE)
 }else{
   return(TRUE)
 }
}`

and I am using the following function in apply  function in base indexing :

`c4[apply(c4, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) any(prime.function(x))),]`

but unfortunately, the code throws error.

I would love to hear any suggestion about the code. Hope I am clear on the explanation side.

Comment: First off, `prime.function` is a *very* inefficient way to check whether `x` is prime. For example and amongst other things, it suffices to check for numbers up to `sqrt(x)` rather than `x-1`. Secondly you state that *"the code throws error"*; what errors are produced? For example, at the moment `prime.function` has a typo (`TURE` instead of `TRUE`); are there other errors? It seems to me you want to check whether a row number is prime or not. If that is the case, why loop through the entire `data.frame`? Unless I misunderstood, `df[sapply(1:nrow(df), prime.function), ]` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Using the prim function provided here: [Prime number function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767408/prime-number-function-in-r)

```
is.prime <- function(n) n == 2L || all(n %% 2L:max(2,floor(sqrt(n))) != 0)
```

The following code will do the job:

```
# replicate your data frame
c4_check <- c4

# replace the items with booleans in the replicate
c4_check[] <- sapply(unlist(c4), is.prime)

# filter the original data frame using the replicate
c4[rowSums(c4_check) != 0, ]
```

**Update:**

@Maurits Evers' answer in his comment is much better:

```
c4[sapply(1:nrow(c4), is.prime), ]
```