# find a prime number after random x in r

Tags: r

I made this code and now I wanna find the smallest prime number greater than a x?  For example, given 4, I need 5; given 7, I need 11.

```
my_number = function(n) {
    rangeOfNumbers = 2:(n-1)
    if(any(n%%rangeOfNumbers == 0)){
      return(FALSE)
    }
    else return(TRUE)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be an option using a `while` loop, based on [this function to find if a number is a prime number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767408/prime-number-function-in-r)

```
first_prime <- function(n){

  is.prime <- function(n) {
    if (n == 2) {
      TRUE
    } else if (any(n %% 2:(n-1) == 0)) {
      FALSE
    } else { 
      TRUE
    }
  }
n <- n+1

while(is.prime(n) == FALSE) {
  n <- n+1
}
print(n)
}

> first_prime(10)
[1] 11
> first_prime(11)
[1] 13
> first_prime(12)
[1] 13
> first_prime(14)
[1] 17
> first_prime(20)
[1] 23
```

Comment: As this risks to be concerned by performances, you may replace the "n %% 2:(n-1)" by "n %% 2:int(sqrt(n))"

Comment: @Vince May work (although trying it throwed an error in my session). Moreover, it requires `rlang::int` and does not work with `base` alone.

Comment: Sorry, I don t know well R, maybe the int conversion should be done otherwise.

Comment: You could use `ceiling(sqrt(n))` to round up to the next highest integer

Comment: In addition to @Vince , you can increment n by 2 if the starting n is odd to speed up a bit more when dealing with large numbers