# Find maximum Prime Difference between Range using R ( HackerEarth )

Tags: r

**PROBLEM STATEMENT :**

Find maximum difference between the prime numbers in the given range. [L,R]

**SOME CONDITION EXAMPLE :**

**Range: [ 1, 10 ]**
The maximum difference between the prime numbers in the given range is 5.

Difference = 7 - 2 = 5

**Range: [ 5, 5 ]** There is only one distinct prime number so the maximum difference would be 0.

**Range: [ 8 , 10 ]** There is no prime number in the given range so the output for the given range would be -1.

**Range: [ 2 - 7 ]** . This should return 5.  [ 7 - 2 ] = 5

**R Code :**

The below R code works fine in R studio for all input I have passed. ***But when I ran the similar code in hackerEarth Env. Getting Errors***

```
Input :

5
5 5
2 7
8 10
10 20
4 5
```

```
input <- readLines(stdin(), n=6)
total <- as.numeric(input[1]) 
val <- 1:total
for (i in 1:total )  
 {
   val[i] <- input[i+1]

} 

df <- data.frame(val) 
df <- str_split_fixed(df$val, " ", 2)
lf <- data.frame(l=df[,1],r=df[,2])
dat <- as.data.frame(sapply(lf, as.numeric))

#Find Prime Sequence
sieve <- function(n)
{
   n <- as.integer(n)
   if(n > 1e6) stop("n too large")
   primes <- rep(TRUE, n)
   primes[1] <- FALSE
   last.prime <- 2L
   for(i in last.prime:floor(sqrt(n)))
   {
      primes[seq.int(2L*last.prime, n, last.prime)] <- FALSE
      last.prime <- last.prime + min(which(primes[(last.prime+1):n]))
   }
   which(primes)
}
#Find Next Prime
np <- function(x){
 if (x==1L | x==2L) {return(2L)}
 else { 
  temp <- x+1
  test <- 2:x
  while( any( (temp %% test) == 0 ) ){
    temp <- temp+1
  }
  temp
} }
# Pass LR
prime <- function(l,r)
{

    if (l==r) { return(0L) }    
    else if( (r - np(l)) == 0 ) { return(0L) }  
    else if( max(sieve(r)) - np(l) < 0)  { return(-1L) }    
    else { return(max(sieve(r)) - np(l)) }  

}


cat(mapply(prime,dat$l,dat$r),sep='\n')
```

```
R studio Output :
0
5
-1
8
0
```

Hacker Earth Output :

Getting below two Errors

1. Error in seq.int(2L * last.prime, n, last.prime) :
   wrong sign in 'by' argument
   Calls: mapply ->  -> sieve
   In addition: Warning message:
   In if (is.character(fun)) fun <- get(fun, mode = "function", envir = parent.frame()) :
   closing unused connection 3 (stdin)
   Execution halted
2. Time Limit Exceeded

Is there a better way to achieve the desired results in less than a second. Corrections/Suggestions are highly appreciated

Comment: If you want to speed up, you should use sieve algorithm. An implementation can be referred to is https://stackoverflow.com/a/3790309/12158757

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Your algorithm searches for all primes in the interval. Let's consider the range between 1 and 1 000 000. That means that you will check for 1 000 000 numbers whether they are prime. That uses up a lot of storage resources, you unnecessarily store the primes between 1 and 1 000 000. It also wastes a lot of computational resources, since you unnecessarily compute this 1 000 000 times.

Instead, a much more efficient way to do this both in terms of storage and computation efficiency is to:

- find the first prime in the range via a loop starting from 2 (because 1 is not a prime, no need for check whether it's prime) and **which stops when the first prime is found**
- find the last prime in the range via a loop starting from total backwards (total, total - 1, ...) until you find the last prime **and then the loop stops**
- with the two very efficient loops above, you will know the first and the last prime if they exist
- if there is a first and a last prime, then compute their difference, otherwise return a default value, like 0

Excuse me for not writing code for you, but I'm not fluent in R.